# Where is the straightening tool that allows ~4 guide lines?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transform, perspective, crop

After numerous queries involving various combinations of "straighten perspective guides transform photoshop adobe" I've come across many new ways to change the perspective of an image but I can't find the tool I used to use.

I'm looking for a tool that allows you to draw multiple straight lines on your image, and then it warps the image to make those lines horizontal or vertical. It is, quite simply, a multi-line version of Photoshop's `straighten` tool under `crop`.

I believe this tool was in Photoshop, but maybe I'm wrong. Perhaps it was in the Camera Raw Filter? As of the 2020 update, though, it seems there is no crop tool in Camera Raw Filter?

If the tool was, indeed, in Camera Raw Filter, has it moved elsewhere?

There are many perspective tools in Photoshop but for a very linear image this seems by far the easiest.

Answer (score 1):

It is called the "Perspective Crop Tool" and I find it nested with/ under the crop tool in the tool sidebar.

Just click on the corners you want aligned horizontal and vertical and it creates a grid over the selected area (there is a checkbox to "show grid" in the control bar). You can then re-size the entire area or adjust individual points. Then click on the check mark in the control bar or hit enter/ return to apply the crop.

---

EDIT- not the tool OP was looking for...

Open Camera Raw Filter and go down right side list to Geometry. Click on the far right icon which is called Draw Guides. This allows you to draw *several*  lines on your image which will move the image to vertical and/or horizontal along those lines.

Comment: This is one method however it is not the one I describe and, at least it seems to me, you can only place the edges/corners, you can't adjust internal lines

Comment: OK, I misunderstood you. Open the Camera Raw Filter (as you remembered). On the right side list go down and toggle open "Geometry". Click on the far right icon next to the label "Upright". It is called "Draw Guides" and it allows you to draw several lines to apply horizontal and vertical transformations. Is this the tool you were looking for ?

Comment: thank you thank you thank you

Comment: Answer edited...